# How to fix " Failed to execute goal flex:4.0.0:compile-swc (default-compile-swc) Error occured while compiling"

Tags: linux, maven, apache-flex, compilation

I'm trying to build my project with

```
mvn clean install  -DskipTests
```

It works fine on Windows but I always have the same problem in Linux despite same project, same maven and same Java versions.

> Failed to execute goal maven.plugins:maven.plugins.flex:4.0.0:compile-swc (default-compile-swc) on project fo.flex-view: Error occured while compiling.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It looks like you are compiling a Flash / Flex application using Maven.  Which maven plugin are you using?  Is the Flex SDK installed and configured on the Linux machine?